# What implications comes with using a getter pattern rather than a typical immutable member?

Tags: flutter, dart

Given these two simple design patterns for static values, what are the implications of each of them? Are they identical in performance and memory usage in Dart/Flutter applications when accessing their members?

#### Example A: `MyStringsGetters`

```dart
const strings = MyStringsGetters();

class MyStringsGetters {
  const MyStringsGetters();
  get helloWorld => 'Hello, World';
}
```

#### Example B: `MyStringsMembers`

```dart
const strings = MyStringsMembers();

class MyStringsMembers {
  const MyStringsMembers();
  static const helloWorld = 'Hello, World';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example A** will be more inefficient. Getters are essentially methods that are called at run time and their response is not cached. Yes, the class instance is `const` and will be stored in memory only once, but the getter will essentially create a new memory address every time you call it.

I would suggest going with **Example B**.

Here is my proof. I built a dummy app that renders 100 Text instances that display the *Hello World* string using both examples that you shared and here are the results:

| Example A | Example B |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

You can clearly see the memory allocated is much smaller in `Example B` and the main reason is that the getter will allocate new memory addresses.

You can also use the Memory DevTool to play with these kind of questions. Here is the code that I used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

const strings = MyStringsMembers();

class MyStringsMembers {
  const MyStringsMembers();
  static const helloWorld = 'Hello, World';
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: MyStringsMembers.helloWorld,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _widgets() {
    List<Widget> result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      result.add(Text(MyStringsMembers.helloWorld));
    }
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: _widgets()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you are interested in more tips on how to improve the performance of your Flutter app, I wrote an article [here](https://jup.dev/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-flutter-app/).

**Is this documented somewhere?**

I tried looking through the documentation and couldn't find much on this. The closest info that I found in the [Dart Programming Language Specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf) book page 37.

> Getters are functions (9) that are used to retrieve the values of object properties.

Given that you are not storing the value of the string as an object property and the getter is essentially just a helper function that does what you specify, it will end up allocating memory every time is called. `"Hello world"` is essentially saying create a new string in memory with this content.

Comment: This was my intuitive thought, and I agree with your statements/approach. I couldn't find any docs that support the statement: "Getters are essentially methods that are called at run time and their response is not cached." Do you have any written documentation to support that? I like to read about it; otherwise, excellent answer!

Comment: I appended the answer to your comment in the answer. The short story is that I couldn't find much info on getters, but I found some proof that confirms that getters are just functions that one can use to retrieve the value of different objects. Given that the object you are retrieving with your getter is not an object property and you dynamically allocate the string without storing it anywhere, you end up creating new instances every time the function gets called.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of. Example A, getter will be called on object of MyStringsGetters. i.e.
`strings.helloWorld`

But example B, helloWorld will be called on MyStringsMembers. i.e. you can't call `strings.helloWorld` like in Example A.

You should use Example B version if same value is retuned from a getter in a class irrespective of instance (hence the `static` keyword).

But Example A can be modified to

```
void main(){
  print(MyClass("Hello World").value);
  print(MyClass("Thank you").value);
}

class MyClass {
  final String _value;
  const MyClass(String value) : _value=value;
  String get value => _value;
}
```

You will get output

```
Hello World
Thank you
```

MyClass is still a `const` which means all the possible values of MyClass will be known as compile time.